# Create hook menu with custom module (child/%)

Tags: hooks, navigation

In my custom module I want to create menu with the name "**child/%**" is it possible. When I create menu "**child/test**", whenever I load the page http://localhost/project/child/test it gives error page could not found. so if I run http://localhost/project/%E2%80%8Bchild/test like this it is working.
Its confusing, Kindly clarrify.

Thanks,
John.

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Answer (score 0):

try to follow this code

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function example_menu() {
  // In this example, the third parameter will be passed.
  $items['admin/example/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example of first parameter being passed',
    'description' => 'This has a page arguments index of two because the wildcard occurs at the 3rd parameter',
    'page callback' => 'one',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
  );
  // The third and fourth parameters are being passed, hence we need to create an array with values 2 and 3 for the page arguments key
  $items['admin/example/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example of multiple parameters being submitted',
    'description' => 'Example of multiple parameters being submitted',
    'page callback' => 'two',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * One parameter being passed.
 */
function one($one) {
    return $one;
}

/**
 * Two parameters being passed.
 */
function two($one, $two) {
    return $one . ' ' . $two;
}
```

Thank You.